# Scan a folder full of videos, get the file name and file path of each video and add it to the movies db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

New to .net MVC here. I am trying to scan a folder I added to my project labeled MovieMedia and add the name and file path with extension to my existing movie database. Im not sure how to do this. Currently I am adding each one in the seed method this way

```
 new Movies
 {
  Title = "Jurassic Park",
  FilePath = @"~/MovieMedia/Jurassic Park.mp4"
 }
```

or by manually adding the details on a create page.

The goal here is to get the title and path to each movie already in the MovieMedia folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below method to get all file list with path, you have to pass directory path as parameter.

```
    public List<String> DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        List<String> files = new List<String>();
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
        {
            files.Add(f);
        }
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            files.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
        }
        return files;
    }
```